# Query an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a project where I need to query an Excel spreadsheet.  Basically I need to read a two column Excel spreadsheet into a dictionary table.  I have a database of error codes and descriptions for each code. The project requires Excel (Excel 2007 compatible .xlsx) because the user wants to add new Key/Description pairs by editing an Excel spread sheet.

The idea is that I am going to get a list of error codes and I simply want to be able to display a table in a worksheet with error code and the associated description from the Excel spreadsheet, or no description found. 
I figure if I can get the table (which is not very long) into a dictionary table the rest would straight forward but I cannot even find a starting point using the current version C# and 4.5.2 .NET API.  I just need to open the worksheet and read the two column table into a dictionary table and I am off to the races.

Can someone please get me started in the right direction please?

Comment: Why not convert the excel document to a csv when they give it to you.  It will be simpler to read if you can't figure out how to read an excel file.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `OleDbConnection` to get the data from Excel.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source="
                +  xlsx file with path
                + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
stbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [" + SHEETNAME_HERE + "$A1:B65]");
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), con);

DataSet dsXLS = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(dsXLS);
```

Once you have the data filled up, you can fetch the data in dictionary or any other object of List Enumerable.